# Remove Active State if Clicked Again

Tags: jquery

I have 4 hidden divs that toggle back and forth (hiding all except current), and re-hides current when link is clicked again.

I managed to add an active state to the currently clicked link to change the link color, but when toggled to re-hide that div, the link remains active... the active state only removes from the link if another link is click, but not if the current link is clicked again.

There's an "on click" function... we need an "off click" LOL!

```
CSS:
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
background-color: #cfe6a6;
width:100%;
display:block;
position:inherit;
padding:15px;
}
a {color:blue;}
#link1.active, #link2.active, #link3.active, #link4.active {color: #95C837;}

HTML:
<a href="#" id="link1"/>LINK 1</a>, <a href="#" id="link2"/>LINK 2</a>, <a   href="#" id="link3"/>LINK 3</a> and <a href="#" id="link4"/>LINK 4</a>

<br/>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;">DIV 1</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none;">DIV 2</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none;">DIV 3</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none;">DIV 4</div>

SCRIPT:
$("#link1").on('click', function() {
$("#link1").addClass('active');
  $("#div1").slideToggle();
$("#link2,#link3,#link4").removeClass('active');
  $("#div2,#div3,#div4").slideUp();
});
$("#link2").on('click', function() {
$("#link2").addClass('active');
  $("#div2").slideToggle();
$("#link1,#link3,#link4").removeClass('active');
  $("#div1,#div3,#div4").slideUp();
});
$("#link3").on('click', function() {
$("#link3").addClass('active');
  $("#div3").slideToggle();
$("#link1,#link2,#link4").removeClass('active');
  $("#div1,#div2,#div4").slideUp();
});
$("#link4").on('click', function() {
$("#link4").addClass('active');
  $("#div4").slideToggle();
$("#link1,#link2,#link3").removeClass('active');
  $("#div1,#div2,#div3").slideUp();
});
```

Here is my fiddle for the genius out there!

https://jsfiddle.net/flipflopmedia/rgt16b72/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check visibility of the div to know if it was open or closed. For example this way:

```
...

 $("#link1").on('click', function(){
    var xthis = this;
    $("#div1").slideToggle(function(){
       if($(this).is(":hidden")){
           $(xthis).removeClass('active');
       }else{
           $(xthis).addClass('active');
       }
    });
 ...
 });

...
```

The better idea would be to make one function for whole menu, by pairing items... for example like this:

```
 $(".menu_item").on('click', function(){
    console.log('click');
    var xthis = this;
    $("#"+$(xthis).attr('rel')).slideToggle(function(){
       if($(this).is(":hidden")){
           $(xthis).removeClass('active');
       }else{
           $(xthis).addClass('active');
       }
    });
    $(".menu_item").not(xthis).removeClass('active');
    $(".menu_content").not("#"+$(xthis).attr('rel')).slideUp();
 });
```

Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/rgt16b72/26/

(please note that I had to add additional tags to menu elements)

Comment: This does work, but I'm having a few issues that are likely my fault. My href tag should have read: href="javascript:void(0);" ... I pasted it wrong in my question and instead used href="#". The pound sign does not work on my page, because the page jumps to the top when the link is clicked. Your script seemed to work okay, but at some random point while clicking the links, it stops working correctly and the DIVs group together vs. closing the current and opening the next.

Comment: Seems to only happen when you click on the 1st link first? See here if you like (initial connection to page is slow): http://stemcellsafari.epizy.com/conditions-treated/degenerative/

Comment: not sure where to look, but initial connection for me is fine, `javascript:void(0)` is just wrong syntax, and it halts all other scripts because of an error...

Comment: Nevermind all of that. It's working beautifully with my page now... it was my error. My first DIV was typed incorrectly with misplaced quotes: <div id="div1" style="display:none; class="menu_content"">

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the `link` is active or not, and add or remove the `class` respectively, e.g.

```js
$("a").on('click', function(){
  removeOrAddClass(this);
  $("#" + $(this).attr('rel')).slideToggle();
  $("div").not("#" + $(this).attr('rel')).slideUp();
});
     
function removeOrAddClass(el) {
  if ($(el).hasClass('active')) {
    $(el).removeClass('active');
  }
  else {
    $(el).addClass('active');
  }
  $('a').not(el).removeClass('active');
}
```

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
background-color: #cfe6a6;
width:100%;
display:block;
position:inherit;
padding:15px;
}
a {color:blue;}
#link1.active, #link2.active, #link3.active, #link4.active {color: #95C837;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link1" rel="div1"/>LINK 1</a> 
<a href="#" id="link2" rel="div2"/>LINK 2</a> 
<a href="#" id="link3" rel="div3"/>LINK 3</a> and ...
<a href="#" id="link4" rel="div4"/>LINK 4</a>

<br/>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div3" style="display:none;">DIV 3</div>
<div id="div4" style="display:none;">DIV 4</div>
```

Comment: I want to thank you for the time you took to answer my question. Your script clearly works, however, it wasn't happy with other elements in my page for whatever reason. I had less issues to workout using the answer from Flash, but I certainly want to give you a thumbs up for sure!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/rgt16b72/30/

```js
$("a").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $('#' + $(this).attr("targetId")).slideUp();
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('active')
      .siblings('a').removeClass('active');
    $('#' + $(this).attr("targetId")).slideToggle()
      .siblings('div').slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4 {
background-color: #cfe6a6;
width:100%;
display:block;
position:inherit;
padding:15px;
}
a {color:blue;}
#link1.active, #link2.active, #link3.active, #link4.active {color: #95C837;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="link1" targetId="div1"/>LINK 1</a>, <a href="#" id="link2" targetId="div2"/>LINK 2</a>, <a href="#" id="link3" targetId="div3"/>LINK 3</a> and <a href="#" id="link4" targetId="div4"/>LINK 4</a>

<br/>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;">DIV 1</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none;">DIV 2</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none;">DIV 3</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none;">DIV 4</div>
```

You should never use multiple methods for the same purpose, rather use different parameters or HTML attributes.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply! I went with the first answer from Flash. I checked your fiddle and didn't do what I was needing. When you click off the link (with all DIVs closed) the link color did not revert back to blue, as I was needing. My issue is resolved, but I just wanted to mention that and say thanks!